# Error HH411: The library @hardhat/console.so, imported from contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol, is not installed. Try installing it using npm

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, npx, hardhat

I have installed all devDependencies & dependencies.

[Dependencies installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i78y.png)

But while running the cmd (npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost) getting the Error,

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYSYp.png)

Error HH411: The library @hardhat/console.so, imported from contracts/NFTMarketcts/NFTMarketplace.sol, is not installed. Try installing it using npm.

Answers / Solutions of the Error

Comment: The error message looks a bit strange. That should be `hardhat/console.sol`. I.e. `sol` not `.so`. Where does you `NFTMarketplace.sol` come from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)